# How do I use PHP to create a dynamic answer based on a users input from a form?

Tags: php, jquery

I basically want to create a simple text input with a button that says submit. And using PHP I want to be able to give a different answer based on what the users input was. For example, if the user inputs the number 6, I want it to display "You are on week 6" - Can someone help me? I am having some trouble putting this together to get it to work.

Comment: I suggest studying some PHP tutorials, this is really too basic.

Answer (score 1):

The simple version is something like this:

```
<?php

echo "You are on week".$_POST['week'];
```

Your form would look like:

```
<form method="post">
     <input name="week" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But it's much more complicated than this; you have to validate the input and worry about injection attacks, among other things.

**You will get better help on here if you provide some code that you already have in place and ask specific questions about particular problems.**

Answer (score -1):

When your form is

```
<form method="post">
     <input name="nameOfYourInput"/>
     <input type="submit" value="sendButton"/>
</form>
```

This doesn't depend on serverside language be it php or any other language.

Specific to php is only the printing of the variable in the input field.

which can be achieved by

```
<?php    
echo "You are on week" . $_POST['nameOfYourInput'];
```

The $_POST is variable which is passed(automaticaly) to the server with the http request.

Comment: "When you have a hammer, everything is a nail" (I added a downvote)